# How to split the string vector array in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

How to split the string vector in C++?

The input string values are read from the file, and it's format is like below.

```
P00 ARRIVAL:3   CPU:1   I/O:3   CPU:7   I/O:1   CPU:3   
P01 ARRIVAL:2   CPU:9   
P02 ARRIVAL:0   CPU:6   
P03 ARRIVAL:4   CPU:1   
P04 ARRIVAL:0   CPU:5
```

However, I need just the value like,

```
p00 3   1   3   7   1   3
p01 2   9
p02 0   6
...
```

And this is my part of code. The file is read by a line by line, and each line is saved on string vector array.

```
vector<string> procList; // file


void readProc(char *filename) {

    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        procList.push_back(str);
    }

    file.close();

    for (int i = 0, size = procList.size(); i < size; ++i) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("[%s] \n"), procList[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the format fixed? First element followed by list of key/value pairs separated with : ?

Comment: Format is fixed, and it is split with the tab(/t).
procList[1] = P00 (tab) ARRIVAL:3 (tab)   CPU:1 (tab)  I/O:3 (tab)  CPU:7  (tab) I/O:1 (tab)  CPU:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regexps for parsing:

[**live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3ae060930d45009e)

```
#include <regex>

std::vector<std::string> example = {
        "P00 ARRIVAL:3   CPU:1   I/O:3   CPU:7   I/O:1   CPU:3",
        "P01 ARRIVAL:2   CPU:9",
        "P02 ARRIVAL:0   CPU:6",
        "P03 ARRIVAL:4   CPU:1",
        "P04 ARRIVAL:0   CPU:5"
};
std::regex re{"[\\w\\d]+:(\\d+)"};
for (auto s : example) {
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> it{s.begin(), s.end(), re, 1};
    decltype(it) end{};
    while (it != end) std::cout << *it++ << ":";
}
```

will output:

```
3:1:3:7:1:3:
2:9:
0:6:
4:1:
0:5:
```

With regex_token_iterator you could also specify to iterate over name and value in your data. You specify in regexp two groups (using parentheses), and then specify in constructor to regex_token_iterator which groups (sub matches) to include during iteration using: {1, 2}.

[**live**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/452e57734d4d7c89)

```
std::regex re{R"(([\w\d/]+):(\d+))"};
for (auto s : example) {
    std::cout << "\n";
    using reg_itr = std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator>;
    for (reg_itr it{s.begin(), s.end(), re, {1,2}}, end{}; it != end;) {
        std::cout << *it++ << ":"; std::cout << std::stoi(*it++) << " ";
    }
}
```

will output:

```
ARRIVAL:3 CPU:1 I/O:3 CPU:7 I/O:1 CPU:3 
ARRIVAL:2 CPU:9 
ARRIVAL:0 CPU:6 
ARRIVAL:4 CPU:1 
ARRIVAL:0 CPU:5
```

Comment: What is type of output? is the string? char? 
I want to convert it to int value. How can I do that?

Comment: Oh it is string, so I use the stoi();

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is `id {key:value}`. The following code utilizes `stringstream` and `getline`. Might have problems, I haven't tested.

```
vector<string> procList; // file


void readProc(char *filename) {

    std::ifstream file(filename);
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        std::stringstream in(str);
        std::stringstream out;
        std::string temp;

        in>>temp;
        out<<temp;

        while(getline(in, temp, ':')) {
            in>>temp;
            out<<"\t"<<temp;
        }

        procList.push_back(out.str());
    }

    file.close();

    for (int i = 0, size = procList.size(); i < size; ++i) {
        _tprintf(TEXT("[%s] \n"), procList[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: while(getline(in, temp, ":")) <-- has some error. Does it need some header?

Comment: you need sstream fstream iostream and string headers.

Comment: Also made a small fix, delimeter for getline should be a char.